# Can I use posted salary ranges as my extected salary range?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I've recently found a job that I'm very interested in taking. Most jobs, where I am working, do not list a salary range. They usually will ask your current salary and/or ask for your expected salary. I've already been asked my expected salary, but I delayed the question by saying, that I'd like to know more about the role before I can give that information out, which was gladly accepted at the time.

I did a lot of searching and I saw this position was listed on several different websites with different ranges. The one that I contacted the employer on, had the highest range, which is quite a bit higher than what I am making now, but the other websites' listed salary ranges listed are also still acceptable.

How can I negotiate for the best possible salary and can I use these posted salary ranges as my expected salary range? Can I be direct and say I saw them posted where we contacted and believe this is good?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Should I use the range posted on the same site that he and I met on? They are significantly higher. Like by several thousand a month

Comment: If I say yes and you get the job, you'll appreciate the advice for the extra thousands.  If I say yes and you don't get the job, your natural instinct will be to blame my bad advice.  If I say no and you get the job, you'll wonder if you should have gone higher.  Ultimately, there's lots of factors that affect how good you appear to them, how much they are willing to pay for that.  Be prepared to justify your idea, and consider in advance how much you're happy to risk/adjust.  It *might* also be good to introduce supporting evidence before objections are even raised.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try not to blame you either way. I have my rock bottom number in my mind and I'm already working so even if I don't get the job then I won't cry. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to aim high. You can negotiate downwards after that. It's a negotiation rather than a set price. So as long as you're not being unrealistic go for the higher range. If they want you they will make you an offer which you can then accept or not.

Right now it appears you're not under pressure to find another position, so you have the time and leverage to try and get the best that you can for yourself.

Comment: Good point. Will take that in to consideration. I'm thinking to bring the range from the job site that him and I met on and of course saying I want the high range. You think that is effective? Or maybe just choose mid of that? Even the low number of the range on that site is significantly higher than what I'm making now. I just don't want him to use my current salary as a way to bring it down even further.

Comment: Why would you give him your current salary? That just weakens your negotiating position before you even start. I've never given that info, info is leverage in a negotiation, you don't just give it away because someone asks. I just say I can't tell them, it's confidential.

Comment: Indeed. Was also planning on keeping that a secret. Especially since what I'm doing now and what I would be doing there is pretty much unrelated, other than still in software.

Comment: It's all about money for me, so personally I'd go for high end if I wasn't desperate for a job and see what they offer. But you'd know best if you fit the job well enough to do that.

Comment: It's not about money actually. I'm not really liking where I am, but if I can move to a better career and more than double my salary (if I get in at the highest end) then that would be a double win.

Comment: yes, I just mentioned my personal motivation, I was never really happy working anywhere unless I owned the place. Good luck.

Comment: turns out that high offer was a mistake on their part, or so they said. but waiting for final offer.

Comment: Pro's don't make simple mistakes with money

Comment: So you think it's part of a negotiating task to push down my price? Can be... hard to say. It was only like that in one posting out of 3 or 4. So anything is possible.