# How to approach in an interview a lower salary than the posted salary ranges

Tags: interviewing, salary

I was contacted recently by a recruiter. They were interested by my CV and my previous experience (not a lot, but they mentioned they liked the experience, not that they thought it was little). I finished my studies in that country, although I came back to mine to finish with some issues. Both are in Europe and in mine, jobs in general have lower salaries (being my field quite well paid even in my own country). I also checked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/86793/can-i-use-posted-salary-ranges-as-my-extected-salary-range) and [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61904/why-would-a-recruiter-want-to-put-someone-into-a-direct-hire-job-at-a-lower-sala) on this site, to have more of a clue.

After the first interview, **I had to do a second one but I was told the person was busy, so we could skip that process, so they asked me for expected salaries**. I did a previous research on salary ranges of that position in that country (also in different areas of that country as in the most costly living areas, salaries are higher in that country, probably anywhere).

I told them that from my research, those numbers were it (min and max). Then, **from the salary range the offered me, the max was lower than the minimum salary from the min-max salary stated in different websites**. "This is the salary range our (position) earn". They told me to do some more research and tell them what I think. I sent them an email regarding other concerns (more about projects and technology used) before making a decision. Still no update.

I indeed did some **more research**, in websites in the language of that country, searching for salaries in that specific company for that and other positions. **Those salaries match the lowest range from the min-max range of the ones I saw of general salaries for X position in that country**. So I feel kind of lied, but maybe my perception is wrong.

How should I approach this, if I should approach this at all. The job is not my dream job nor have I pressure or rush to find a job right now.

**TL;DR**

I was offered a salary lower than the min salary from salary ranges (min and max), on different websites and on specific websites of salaries of that company. Should I approach this? Should I run away?

Comment: Are you sure your research is accurate and directly comparable with the position offered? There is often variation in salaries due to things such as the location (big city companies pay more), whether it's a start-up (which may pay less but offer equity or other potential future benefits), the precise nature of the position, other benefits, etc. Salaries quoted in adverts may not be entirely accurate: companies are going to exaggerate. There are organisations which conduct salary research and sell companies information on what's the going rate, which are likely to be more accurate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How should I approach this, if I should approach this at all. The job
> is not my dream job nor have I pressure or rush to find a job right
> now.

It doesn't matter what your research turned up. The only thing that matters is the offered salary.

If you feel the salary is too low for you, either

- make a counter offer ("I wouldn't accept less than X")
- continue to negotiate
- decline the offer and find a different job that pays more

No need to feel offended. No need to suspect anyone is lying.

Answer (score 2):

There's the salary offered, there's the salary that you would want, and there's the question whether you take the job right now or whether you look elsewhere first. The salary offered depends on two factors: How good an impression you made during the interview/how much they want you, and how tight they are with money.

If the salary offered below your minimum, then you don't take the offer. If it is at the lower end of your expected range, then you tell them that you will think about it and continue looking for better offers - if you figure out that the higher end of your expected range is not achievable, then you go back to them. If they want to pressure you into a decision right now, you tell them that you need time to think about it.

You get pressured in two cases: If they want to get you cheap and use pressure to make you accept a low offer, or if they really need you urgently and their offer is actually good to make you start immediately. So a good offer you better accept, because it will be gone soon. A low offer, no matter how much they try to pressure you, will likely be available next month.

Answer (score 1):

You may have blown it by mentioning "research" at all during the interview.  Now that gives the company the capability to use "research" as a wedge, since you put that concept on the table.  You say, "my research says XYZ".  They counter, "well *our* research says ABC".  It's a no-win.

You're at a place now where you have less leverage than if you'd just walked in the door and stated a desired range without saying that you determined it by research.

If you're in no rush, let this one go.  Be smarter next time about what you introduce into negotiations.

Comment: So it would be better to JUST say "X amount" (a range will allow them to go to the minimum more than the median), and if told a lower salary than the one I have researched (without mentioning the research part to them, just X number), reply that I think it's low/I will think about it?

Comment: @M.K Pretty much.  Sometimes an offer just isn't going to work for you.  If you have other options, don't even bother with the "think about it" approach.  You can be direct: "thanks for your interest, but I can't work with that number."